# Flot chart multiple axes are not configured properly

Tags: javascript, flot

I am expecting pretty weird problem with flot v.0.7. I have multiple axes, configured like that:

```
var plotData = [
    { data: data1 },
    { data: data2, yaxis: 2 }];

var options = {
    selection: { mode: "x" },
    xaxis: { mode: "time" },
    yaxis: [
      { min: 0 },
      {
        min: 0, 
position: "right",
zoomRange: false,
alignTicksWithAxis: 1,
tickFormatter: formatter,
      }
    ],
    grid: { markings: weekendAreas },
    zoom: { interactive: true },
    grid: {
        clickable: true,
        hoverable: true,
        borderWidth: 1,
    },
    legend: { show: false },
};

var plot = $jq.plot(container, plotData, options);
```

But what I get is that both Y series are located on the right (not only second Y series). There is no formatter for my second series tick. Y values can be less then zero, if zooming. If I don't use array type for yaxis and define it as it would only be one series, then everything works fine. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Instead of `yaxis: [ ... ]`, use `yaxes: [ ... ]`.

See the section of the docs entitled [Multiple Axes](https://github.com/flot/flot/blob/master/API.md#multiple-axes) for more info.

Comment: Damn, I thought there must be some weird misspelled word or silly error. Thanks for pointing me this out!

Comment: i looked at that for like 5 minutes before i realized the difference was the i changing to an e... thanks though, that was exactly my problem